# WiFi repeater on two DIR-320 routers

Tags: wifi, d-link

I own 2 `DIR-320` WiFi routers from `DLINK`. I also own 3-floor house. I installed single router on 3rd floor and found that signal strength on 1st floor is poor. I'd like to install 2nd `DIR-320` on 1st floor and join them with Ethernet cable. Is that possible to setup them to work in repeater mode (so both are sharing same WiFi network and I just don't have to switch between networks)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that repeater is the mode you want.

The trivial solution is to use the same SSID (Be sure that you use different channels, otherwise you may have connection problems depending on the signal strength of the other AP)

Do you want encryption to your network

Comment: Encryption - well, I think so? Is encryption the problem for same ESSID on different channels?

Comment: For two AP not really. Could can do it manually. If you had more APs then it would be a little more complex.

Just make sure that you 'll have the same password in both APs

Answer (score 0):

Repeater Mode best way to increase the signal strngth in dark area where host router can not reach. To [configure DLink router in repeater mode](https://techtrickszone.com/2019/03/01/tp-link-tl-wr743nd-repeater-mode-configuration/) follow the steps.

1. Login DLink router
2. Go to Wireless - enable repeater
3. scan for your main wifi network signal
4. choose and type the password of main wifi router.
5. save and wait until reboot finish.